# Set orientation to portrait and upside down for iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, orientation, autorotate

I have an iOS project where I want to be able to show the app only in Portrait and Upside Down mode.

I did the following:

1. Checked **Portrait** and **Upside Down** in target -> General -> Deployment Info -> Device Orientation

[image]

2. Added **supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow** function to my App Delegate file:

```
    - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
```

3. Added **shouldAutorotate** and **supportedInterfaceOrientations** to my View Controller files:

```
  override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
  }
  
  override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portraitUpsideDown, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait ];
  }
```

4. Edited the Info.plist file to include Portrait and Upside Down:

[image]

However when I run the app on the iPhone it only shows in Portrait mode not the Upside Down mode when rotate upside down.

I am using Version 13.4.1 (13F100) on Macbook Pro and testing on an iPhone 7 with iOS 15.5.

Comment: Did you try deleting the app, restarting the phone and trying again?  Is rotation lock disabled?

Comment: Yes I deleted the app and installed it again. Rotation lock is disabled. After reinstalling only the first Login view rotates in all orientations now. After the logging in a new view appears with a navigation bar where the rotations don't work.

Answer (score 0):

add this in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portraitUpsideDown
}
```

Comment: That is almost the right solution. When I do that it forces upside down mode but I want Portrait and Upside Down both orientations to work. How can I do that?

Comment: @es1 just return both of them

Comment: I tried that. Now the login screen works correctly (both Portrait and Upside Down). After logging in a new view is opened embedded in a navigation bar which is locked to Portrait only.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. The problem was that in the project there was a 3rd party pod named SideMenuSwift being used which had its preferences set to **.portrait** only. I changed it to **.all** and in **supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor** in AppDelegate I have:

```
return .portraitUpsideDown | .portrait
```